# How to use variable in the query using Azure data factory?

Tags: oracle, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use the trigger_start_time variable in the query as the 2nd parameter to a function of lookup activity.

How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use `concat()` to build the query. What's the whole query statements? Where did want to put the variable TriggerTime?

Comment: My query looks like this : select schema.fn_up_watermark('@{item().table_name}',variable(trigger_start_stime)) from dual

Comment: I have kept the variable trigger_start_time in set variable with value @pipeline.TriggerTime

Comment: Hi @dev333, Please try `@concat('select schema.fn_up_watermark(',Parameter_name,',',variable_name, ') from dual')` in
add dynamic content .

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help ...  This is the query I've given .. it is throwing missing right paranthesis ..  @concat('select schema. fn_up_watermark(',item().table_name,',',variables('trigger_start_time'), ') from dual')

Comment: I just make this example with the query you provide me. You could test that not use the parameter and variable to check where missing the right parentheses.  I think the issue is coming to resolved soon. Come on, waiting for your feedback!

Comment: yeah got it .. It's working now .. Thanks a lot for ur help ..

Comment: You're welcome!  I post it as answer, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `@concat('select schema.fn_up_watermark(',Parameter_name,',',variable_name, ') from dual')` in add dynamic content.

I just make this example with the query you provide me. You could test that not use the parameter and variable to check where missing the right parentheses.

Now, I'm glad to hear the issue is resolved now.

Comment: How do you protect against injection attacks? Does ADF have a quote_literal or quote_ident function to wrap values safely?

Answer (score 0):

You can do away with the variable and simply write:

`select schema.fn_up_watermark('@{item().table_name}','@{pipeline().TriggerTime}') from dual`

assuming both parameters are string.

You could still do SQL injection if you can affect the outer lookup that feeds this ForEach block - you could sanitise the `table_name`s on entering this loop possibly.